# How to display Matlab variable values in Visual Studio after using Matlab Coder?

Tags: c, matlab

I have a very basic Matlab program:

`hello.m`:

```
sprintf('hello')
disp("hello")
```

I then convert it to C code using `codegen -config:dll hello -report` and `codegen -config:lib hello -report`

I then run it in Visual Studio following the steps at : https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/use-a-c-dynamic-library-in-microsoft-visual-studio-project.html

However, after I build and run it in VS, nothing is outputted. I have this as an example because I was hoping there was a way display the Matlab variables in VS. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `fprintf` to print values in the generated code: `fprintf('Hello, World');`. `disp` and printing output by omitting a semicolon don't work in the generated code.